QGIS: extracting desired range values from a raster and removing other values
In QGIS, I've successfully extracted a rainfall range from GeoTIFF file using raster calculator and the range displays. However, the extraction is still showing values below the minimum value of 90mm. How do I effectively clip/mask out the values outside the desired range? I would like to polygonise this extraction without showing all the values!

